# CSS - simple two columns

Tags: css, image, css-float

I have a fluid page (100% width) with this inside:

```
[image-fixed-width] | [text-fluid-width -----------------------------------]
                    | -----------------------------------------------------
                    | -----------------------------------------------------
```

I need the text next to the image not to wrap around it, but to display next to it (like in the illustration), like another column. At the same time, the text needs to span across the entire page width. 
This would be easy to by setting a margin-left to the text, but the problem is that I don't know the exact width of the image. The image size can vary...

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding overflow: hidden; to your content div. That should force it to stick to your columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/BG7FA/

**Edit** This will not work in IE6 (go figure)

Comment: overflow: hidden is magic... it clears floats, it forces columns, it fixes layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `float: left` on both elements with `display: block` on text.

Comment: That doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Sdvt3/ The green should stretch to fill the remaining space.

Comment: For the green to stretch you would need table-based layout, static dimensions or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this is to create a table with 2 cells, one for the image and one for the text. You won't use css but it works with any browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I would expect it to work.

```
<div style='width:100%; overflow:hidden'>
   <img style='float:left'/>
   <div style='float:left'>my text</div>
</div>
```

The logic is that a div (even a floating div) should expand to fill the available space, and the parent will not stretch or allow overflow as both parameters are set.